# Monitor the IP addresses from connections being made from all apps using the network without rooting the Android phone

Tags: android, networking, ip

I am attempting to build an Android app (without having to root the phone) which collects the IP addresses from all the apps' network connections to and from the phone.

I have been tasked with this project and the key point is that the phone must stay unrooted - this (to my knowledge) means I can't use tcpdump or libpcap, since both seem to need the phone to be rooted. One other point, I have found solutions where a VPN Service is used, but, if possible, I am not suppose to use this feature as well, since the app is suppose to work on it's own - without any 'outside' help.

I have been all over stack overflow and many many other sites, trying to find a method to monitor/collect IP addresses and all the solutions I've found required rooting the Android phone. This led me to believe that it wasn't possible, until I found the following app on Google Play.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.borgshell.connectiontrackerfree&hl=en

This app does much more than I need, but it somehow shows the IP addresses of network connections each app is making.

**To summarize:**

Does anyone know a way to collect IP addresses from internal app's network connections

- without rooting the phone
- without using a VPN service

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For all those who are curious about this same issue, I was able to finally figure out how to accomplish this task, without rooting the phone or using a VPN service.

The key to solving this issue, is to look in the following directory on the phone:

> /proc/net/(tcp, tcp6, udp, udp6, etc)

Also, here is some code from an open source project that does basically what I was looking for.

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2010 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package android.net.cts;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import junit.framework.AssertionFailedError;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class ListeningPortsTest extends TestCase {

/** Address patterns used to check whether we're checking the right column in /proc/net. */
private static final List<String> ADDRESS_PATTERNS = new ArrayList<String>(2);

static {
    ADDRESS_PATTERNS.add("[0-9A-F]{8}:[0-9A-F]{4}");
    ADDRESS_PATTERNS.add("[0-9A-F]{32}:[0-9A-F]{4}");
}

/** Ports that are allowed to be listening on the emulator. */
private static final List<String> EXCEPTION_PATTERNS = new ArrayList<String>(6);

static {
    // IPv4 exceptions
    EXCEPTION_PATTERNS.add("00000000:15B3"); // 0.0.0.0:5555   - emulator port
    EXCEPTION_PATTERNS.add("0F02000A:15B3"); // 10.0.2.15:5555 - net forwarding for emulator
    EXCEPTION_PATTERNS.add("[0-9A-F]{6}7F:[0-9A-F]{4}"); // IPv4 Loopback

    // IPv6 exceptions
    EXCEPTION_PATTERNS.add("[0]{31}1:[0-9A-F]{4}"); // IPv6 Loopback
    EXCEPTION_PATTERNS.add("[0]{16}[0]{4}[0]{4}[0-9A-F]{6}7F:[0-9A-F]{4}"); // IPv4-6 Conversion
    EXCEPTION_PATTERNS.add("[0]{16}[F]{4}[0]{4}[0-9A-F]{6}7F:[0-9A-F]{4}"); // IPv4-6 Conversion
}

public void testNoListeningTcpPorts() {
    assertNoListeningPorts("/proc/net/tcp", true);
}

public void testNoListeningTcp6Ports() {
    assertNoListeningPorts("/proc/net/tcp6", true);
}

public void testNoListeningUdpPorts() throws Exception {
    assertNoListeningUdpPorts("/proc/net/udp");
}

public void testNoListeningUdp6Ports() throws Exception {
    assertNoListeningUdpPorts("/proc/net/udp6");
}

private static final int RETRIES_MAX = 6;

/**
 * UDP tests can be flaky due to DNS lookups.  Compensate.
 */
private static void assertNoListeningUdpPorts(String procFilePath) throws Exception {
    for (int i = 0; i < RETRIES_MAX; i++) {
        try {
            assertNoListeningPorts(procFilePath, false);
            return;
        } catch (ListeningPortsAssertionError e) {
            if (i == RETRIES_MAX - 1) {
                throw e;
            }
            Thread.sleep(2 * 1000 * i);
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("unreachable");
}

private static void assertNoListeningPorts(String procFilePath, boolean isTcp) {

    /*
     * Sample output of "cat /proc/net/tcp" on emulator:
     *
     * sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  ...
     * 0: 0100007F:13AD 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0   ...
     * 1: 00000000:15B3 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0   ...
     * 2: 0F02000A:15B3 0202000A:CE8A 01 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0   ...
     *
     */

    File procFile = new File(procFilePath);
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(procFile);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine().trim();

            // Skip column headers
            if (line.startsWith("sl")) {
                continue;
            }

            String[] fields = line.split("\\s+");
            final int expectedNumColumns = 12;
            assertTrue(procFilePath + " should have at least " + expectedNumColumns
                    + " columns of output " + fields, fields.length >= expectedNumColumns);

            String localAddress = fields[1];
            String state = fields[3];

            assertTrue(procFilePath + " should have an IP address in the second column",
                    isAddress(localAddress));

            if (!isException(localAddress) && isPortListening(state, isTcp)) {
                throw new ListeningPortsAssertionError(
                        "Found port listening on " + localAddress + " in " + procFilePath);
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException notFound) {
        fail("Could not open file " + procFilePath + " to check for listening ports.");
    } finally {
        if (scanner != null) {
            scanner.close();
        }
    }
}

private static boolean isAddress(String localAddress) {
    return isPatternMatch(ADDRESS_PATTERNS, localAddress);
}

private static boolean isException(String localAddress) {
    return isPatternMatch(EXCEPTION_PATTERNS, localAddress);
}

private static boolean isPatternMatch(List<String> patterns, String input) {
    for (String pattern : patterns) {
        if (Pattern.matches(pattern, input)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private static boolean isPortListening(String state, boolean isTcp) {
    // 0A = TCP_LISTEN from include/net/tcp_states.h
    String listeningState = isTcp ? "0A" : "07";
    return listeningState.equals(state);
}

private static class ListeningPortsAssertionError extends AssertionFailedError {
    private ListeningPortsAssertionError(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @jesse_english, Me too found the same way, but for monitoring it will be like polling. Every few seconds we have to poll, is it possible to be event based? When ever /proc/net/{tcp,tcp6,udp,udp6...} are updated, automatically we get an event or callback.

Comment: I only ever was able to do it via polling. I couldn't figure out how to set it up automatically. Sorry