# How to detect /proc/net changes in Android

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, monitoring, inotify

I am googling since a week, but didn't found any information on how to monitor the /proc/net/{tcp,tcp6,udp,udp6...} files in Android.

There are couple of threads in the stackoverflow, but are linux platform related and not related to android
1)  [How to detect changes in /proc/net/ files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27460949/how-to-detect-changes-in-proc-net-files)
2) [How can i match each /proc/net/tcp entry to each opened socket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319521/how-can-i-match-each-proc-net-tcp-entry-to-each-opened-socket)
3) [Monitor the IP addresses from connections being made from all apps using the network without rooting the Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731656/monitor-the-ip-addresses-from-connections-being-made-from-all-apps-using-the-net)

Any help will be of great use. Even when I tried implementing the inotify function in c, I was getting event only when I cat the "/proc/net/tcp" file. Not getting when it is updated.

Comment: In case you don't find anything: netlink might send some info that you need. Btw. what info do you want to monitor?

Comment: @domen, I wanted to monitor any application is trying to access the internet. For example, if new entry has been added to the these /proc/net files, then it means that an application with UID (Part or the /proc/net table entry) is trying to access the internet. I tried using netlink sockets but netlink sockets are being disabled in the latest version of Android (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27148536/netlink-implementation-for-the-android-ndk)